# Properties without 'property type' in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, c#-4.0, types, accessor

I am converting a Delphi code to a C#.

I have a complex classes structure where a class is the main *'trunk'* of all its children.

In Delphi I can define the private/protected field with a type and the property for that field with the same type, and not write the type in child classes anymore.

Here is a bit (and functional) example:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  Parent = class
  strict protected
    _myFirstField: Int64;
  public
    property MyFirstField: Int64    write _myFirstField;
  end;

  Child1 = class(Parent)
  public
    // Inherits the write/set behaviour..
    // And it doesn't need to define the type 'over and over' on all child classes.
    //
    // ******* Note MyFirstField here has not type.... ************
    property MyFirstField        read _myFirstField;  // Adding READ behaviour to the property.
  end;

var
  Child1Instance: Child1;
begin
    Child1Instance := Child1.Create;
    //Child1Instance.MyFirstField := 'An String';  <<-- Compilation error because type
    Child1Instance.MyFirstField := 11111;
    WriteLn(IntToStr(Child1Instance.MyFirstField));
    ReadLn;
end.
```

As you can see I don't need to define the property type over and over.
If I need to change the var type in the future, I can change only in the parent class.

Is there any way to get this same behaviour in C#?

Comment: Show what you tried in C# please. As per usual OOP you can have a protected property in the base class and this will be available in the child classes together with the set/get and keeps its type definition of course.

Comment: Isn't it that C# private/protected properties behaviour is exactly the same?

Comment: Truly I must to resume what I want to do:  I have all possible properties declared in an ancestor class and I would like to "publish" only a set of that properties on the child classes.  Without re-declare the whole property... neither type nor accessors.

Comment: No there is no pattern in C# to increase the visibility of a member in a derived class. You need to create a whole new property like in Marc Gravell's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there ist. The types on the public API must be explicit. The only time you aren't explicit is with `var`, which is limited to method variables.

Further, you can't change the signature in C# (adding a public getter in the subclass) - you would have to re-declare it:

```
// base type 
protected string Foo {get;set;}

// derived type
new public string Foo {
    get { return base.Foo; }
    protected set { base.Foo = value; }
}
```

But as the `new` suggests: this is an unrelated property and is *not required* to have the same type.

Comment: Thanks Marc.... Then I must to re-write all the behaviour for the "same" Foo property, even when this behaviour would be the same, don't I ? :-(

Comment: @FerPt no, just proxy to `base.` like in my example

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you can do like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    protected Int64 MyCounter{ get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    protected string ClassName 
   { 
        get 
        {
            return "Child";
        }
    }
}

public class Runner
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new Child();
        c.Counter++;

        Console.WriteLIne(c.Counter);
    }
}
```